# Does windows 10 require a "Virgin HDD" to create a System Image of my "C" Drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, backup

I was using N360 anywhere as my security/virus software and they included a backup program.. I stopped using N360 because it is bloatware and the monthly charge. So I thought that I would use Windows 10 backup and imaging software to do backups and create image of my drive "C". Windoze backup failed on an older Iomega. I immediately did a chkdsk on the Iomega External HDD and no errors were found. I then tried to create an System Image on my newest usb Hdd a 1 year old My passport. Windows said that an error occurred during the attempt to create a system image. Now this points to a possibility of a corrupted file on my main drive "C". However I ran a chkdsk and I performed a "sfc /scannow 3 times on that same C drive and no errors were found all three times. This is extremely frustrating at this point. I am retired and on disability and the pay imaging software I just can't afford right now. Now I have about 400gb of useless data between the two drives!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

No, a fresh, new, backup HDD is not necessary for reliable Windows Image Backups. I successfully make images to just any old external USB drive (2.5 inch) That includes Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 machines.

Your troubleshooting methods sound reasonable. Have you tried a defrag on the destination drives as well as on the Windows C: drive?

If there is no other data on either USB external drive try formatting them, then attempt another image.

Can you borrow someone else's external drive and see if that works? (It's possible that -both- of your external drives have problems)

Try Disk Cleanup on your C: drive, including the second cleanup of System files. (Disk Cleanup is done in two stages for reasons only the geniuses at Microsoft can understand) Disk Cleanup may get rid of some troublesome old files that are getting in the way of your backup.

Windows Image Backup is -usually- reliable, but I have seen it fail if there are problems with the source drive that the usual error checking does not catch/fix.

Answer (score 0):

In order to exclude the WD My Passport drive as the potential cause of the issue I'd recommend running [WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostic](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=E5SGgW) and see if the drive passes both the quick and the extended tests. This way you should be able to rule the drive either safe or not to use.

You may try the same with the other external drive.

You may try using [WD SmartWare](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=MOEtAv) as a backup tool with your WD My Passport drive in order to back your data up.

Is that install of the OS a fresh one or an upgrade from a previous version? Many times a reinstall of the OS fixes the issue.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Good point, Captain_WD about the in-place re-install of the operating system. I have done that numerous times with Windows 10, because the Windows10 ISO is mountable, allowing a user to run Setup.exe. This does preserve personal data and user installed software. That might be a good way for the original poster to correct any operating system problems and allow the system imaging.  -

Comment: Indeed. Windows 10 OS does offer this useful feature and many people on different communities report fixing similar issues this way so I'd give it a try.